# Compiling against Java 7 in JDeveloper 10

Tags: java, compiler-errors, jdeveloper

Is it possible to use Java 7 in JDeveloper 10?

I have an application that works correctly in Java 5. I've updated the java.conf file to point to the Java 7 jdk, and I've changed the project properties to use the same Java 7 J2SE. When I try to compile, however, I get many errors similar to those below:

```
Error: class format error: Object.class on classpath C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\jre\lib\rt.jar/java/lang/Object.class
Error: Object not found 
Error: class format error: Class.class on classpath C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\jre\lib\rt.jar/java/lang/Class.class
Error: Class not found 
Error: class format error: String.class on classpath C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\jre\lib\rt.jar/java/lang/String.class
Error: String not found
```

It seems to be choking on the java definitions themselves. I'm hoping I'm just missing a step somewhere.

Also, upgrading to a later version of JDeveloper is not an option. JDeveloper 12, as far as I've been able to tell, will not deploy to an OC4J instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can not use jdk 1.7 together with jdev 10g. You have to stay with Java 5.
And yes, you can't upgrade to 11g or 12c as they don't use oc4j but Web logic Server.

Comment: I was afraid that'd be the case. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Just to add an additional bit of info for others that may have this issue - you CAN run Jdev 10 on Java 6 by setting the SetJavaHome option in the jdev.conf file to point at the jdk folder of your Java install, like so `SetJavaHome C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_38`. Your folder may differ, of course.

Answer (score 0):

one more notice from me. jdeveloper 10 does not run itself (this means jdeveloper 10g software does not start) with java 64 bit. also not with java6. However, if you successfully started jdeveloper with java 32 bit, you can use java 6 (jdk6) to compile and run your java applications. This can be done by changing the property of your project. Just add there a new java machine 64 bit (under libraries) and let the project us it.